# Как выбрать постоянных клиентов за определенный период?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

Есть вот такая конструкция

```
$orders_total_loyal = $this->db->getValue('
            select sum(t.s)
            from (
                select count(o.id_order) as s
                from ps_orders o
                where o.valid = 1
                and o.invoice_date >= "'.$this->period["from"].'"
                and o.invoice_date <= "'.$this->period["to"].'"
                group by id_customer
                having count(id_order) > 1
            ) as t
        ');
```

Но она выбирает только повторяющиеся за выбранный промежуток. Как правильно сделать, что бы выбрало постоянных клиентов которые были именно в этот промежуток? Сильно тапками не кидайте, я новый в этом всём.

Comment: Все очень сильно зависит от определения понятия "постоянный клиент" и критериев определения этих клиентов. Т.е. как определить - клиент "постоянный" или "переменный"?

Comment: И неплохо бы структуры таблиц, задействованных в поиске "постоянства" клиентов привести. Возможно - с примерами данных в них.

Comment: ну тут вполне конкретно having count(id_order) > 1. Только в этой конструкции он мне вытаскивает за выбранный месяц эти having count(id_order) > 1 а хочется узнать сколько было в этом месяце из тех у кого за всё время having count(id_order) > 1. я просто не понимаю немного как правильно написать

Comment: Тут Вы не правы. Он Вам вытаскивает не за выбранный месяц. Он Вам вытаскивает за период с $this->period["from"] по $this->period["to"] включительно. А какие вы ему рамки поставите - зависит только от Вас.

Comment: Да, всё верно. Но хотелось бы чтобы, вытаскивал заказы выбранного периода но при этом проверял чтобы было having count(id_order) > 1 по всей таблице без временных ограничений

Comment: Молодой человек, Вы уж определитесь, ЧТО именно Вам нужно. В вопросе Вы просите _что бы выбрало постоянных клиентов которые были именно в этот промежуток_. Теперь Вам нужно _заказы_ выбрать...

Comment: Мне нужно выбрать количество заказов которые были сделаны в указанный промежуток постоянными клиентами. Мой же код не ищет клиентов по всей таблице, типа были ли такие клиенты вообще в другое время. А ищет только в этих же временных рамках. Спасибо большое, за желание помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из текста запроса, опубликованного Вами в вопросе, и Ваших комментариев к вопросу код

```php
$orders_total_loyal = $this->db->getValue('
                select id_customer
                from ps_orders o
                where o.valid = 1
                and o.invoice_date >= "'.$this->period["from"].'"
                and o.invoice_date <= "'.$this->period["to"].'"
                group by id_customer
                having count(id_order) > 1
        ');
```

выберет ID пользователей, у которых больше одного заказа за указанный период.

Код

```php
$orders_total_loyal = $this->db->getValue('
                select count(o.id_order) as s
                from ps_orders o
                where o.valid = 1
                and o.invoice_date >= "'.$this->period["from"].'"
                and o.invoice_date <= "'.$this->period["to"].'"
                and id_customer in (
                    select id_customer
                    from ps_orders o
                    where o.valid = 1
                    group by id_customer
                    having count(id_order) > 1)
        ');
```

выдаст количество заказов за указанный период, выполненных клиентами с количеством заказов больше 1.